# How does Membership.GetUser() get the current user logged in?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, cookies

My login sets a cookie with `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Convert.ToString(Login1.UserName), True)` after a successful validation of a username and password.

By using the `Membership.GetUser(username)`, I'm able to successfully load a `MembershipUser` object. **However**, without the username parameter, `Memebership.GetUser()`, the method returns null.

The docs say GetUser(): *Gets the information from the data source and updates the last-activity date/time stamp for the current logged-on membership user.*

Which should be in the cookie, right? I've browsed to cookie, and the session cookie exists but the current logged in user still returns null.

Where does `GetUser()` look for the current logged in user?

How can I save the current logged in user if the validation was successful?

I'm using oracle membership provider.

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcxcb339%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

GetUser() retrieves the user information from the data source and creates a MembershipUser object populated with the returned data. If you use one of the GetUser overloads that does not take a username parameter, GetUser returns the information for the current logged-on membership user. **The current logged-on membership user is identified by the Name of the user in the current HttpContext.**

Comment: Yes, I believe that's how the asp membership provider does. Here, I'm using oracle's